# Turn USB ports off when computer is off

Tags: usb, motherboard

I have Gigabyte Z490UD motherboard, and it keeps powering on USB ports even when computer is off. Since I have USB devices that light up, it's very annoying to have them always on. Is there any ways to disable that?

Edit: Enabling ErP fixed it.

Comment: Always ON USB should be a BIOS setting

Comment: I cannot find it.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1QJi-AMKP6w

Answer (score 1):

The USB Always ON feature is a property of the BIOS and PC design. I have Always ON USB ports on two computers here and the feature can be controlled that way.

If there is no BIOS feature to disable USB Always ON, that means the Board Manufacturer does not support disabling Always ON.

You might contact Gigabyte Support to see what they say.

Comment: Where is the setting usually located?

Comment: You would need to look through all your BIOS settings (location varies by machine model/type) and then if not there, then Gigabyte likely has not made the provision to turn USB off. You need to contact them